# Many to Many ASP.NET MVC Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If you have scenario of a User that has many Roles and Roles that have many users.  Using MVC is there an easy way to bind to the model directly?  If your user class has a list of roles and the roles class has a list of users.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say mvc, you probably think about orm that mvc uses..so it would be helpful if you can specify yours: linq to sql, entity framework or maybe, nhibernate?

Comment: I'm actually trying to use the CTP Entity from that scott gu talks about in his post here : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: Describe a little more the problem you're trying to solve. Model binding is fairly automatic, but depending on the scenario, the binding of deep object graphs can get tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model binding in MVC is fairly strong. You have to remember that naming conventions are important, especially when you start attempting to bind collections.  To bind to a collection, you have to name your form field something to the effect of `name="Model.Roles[]"` (where Model is User; that would be dependent on your view being strongly typed to your User object; change accordingly).  The brackets denote a collection of information being sent back up to the server.  If you want to target a specific point in the collection, perhaps targeting a specific property on that point, you might have something like `name="Model.Roles[x].Id` where x is a valid index in the collection.  It takes some effort to ensure you have these correct, and my approach almost always degrades into sending a custom collection of information back to the server and manually creating the relationships in the action method prior to saving the entity in question.

[Phil Haack has a post about binding to a collection](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx), albeit from 2008.  It's still relevant, however, and might give you more insight into the model binding behavior.